# React-native-async-storage doesn't recognize moment toDate() after killing app

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux, momentjs, asyncstorage

I'm implementing "Add Favorite" and store it those items in async-storage Vs react-redux. It's working fine when after adding and switching from Home Tab to Favorite Tab. But I got the error "date.toDate is not a function" after killing app and go to Favorite Tab.

Any suggestions and solutions? Thank you so much!

**Component**

```
      <CardInfo
      key={data.id.toString()}
      promotionToDate={moment(data.expireDate.toDate()).format('lll')}
      />
```

**Action**

```
export const getPromotionsAction = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: GET_PROMOTION});

  const response = await firebase.firestore().collection('xxxx').get();
  const values = [];
  response.docs.forEach(res => {
    values.push(res.data());
  });
  dispatch({type: GET_PROMOTION, payload: values});
  return values;
};

export const addFavoriteAction = fav => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_PROMOTION_TO_FAVORITE_LIST,
    payload: fav,
  });
};
```

**Store**

```
// import rootReducer from '../redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import PromotionReducer from './reducers';
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {logger} from 'redux-logger';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['setPromotionToFavorites'],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  PromotionReducers: persistReducer(persistConfig, PromotionReducer),
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export type RootStateType = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

**NOTED**
I'm using Firestore, Momentjs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVM36.png)

Comment: Can you try to console log the value in data.expireDate ?

Comment: Thank @VickyAhuja, I found the root cause, it has a problem with the date time format from firestore, maybe it should be store as the String in Redux Store. When comment it out, it's working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the clause for the issue, You can check the answer for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The functions and objects are reference types in JavaScript**, Nearly everything in JavaScript is an object other than six things that are not objects: null, undefined, strings, numbers, boolean, and symbols.

And when we look at the **AsyncStorage**, If we have to store the values in AsyncStorage then **we have to parse the data in the string datatype**.

At that time JSON.stringify is used which converts the objects into a string, and the **functions cannot be converted into strings**.

and We use redux-persist with AsyncStorage which stores the objects into it by JSON.stringify.

In Conslusion, **We have to make sure to convert the functions into JSON Objects by returning the values from them**.